# how to iterate dictionary over list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, for-loop

I have a dictionary following,

```
a = [{"x":"--New Value","y":20},{"x":"--New Value","y":21},{"x":"--New Value","y":27}]
```

While iterating using the code,

```
for i in a:
    print(i["x"])
    print(i["y"])
```

I am getting the following output,

```
--New Value
20
--New Value
21
--New Value
27
```

well what I want the output is,

```
--New Value
20
21
27
```

Any help please ?

Comment: Do you want to group the values by `x` key and print the groups?

Comment: If the string `--New Value` doesn't ever change, you could just print it before the start of the loop (and you might also want to ask why it's in the dictionary in the first place).

Comment: What should happen if `i["x"]` **isn't** equal to `"--New Value"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a dictionary following,

No, you don't, you have a collection of dictionaries. You can group data by the `x` value and print out the groups. Something like the following:

```py
from itertools import groupby

for key, value in groupby(a, lambda x: x['x']):
    print(key)
    for v in value:
        print(v['y'])
```

If you have different keys you might want to sort the data first (depends on desired output):

```py
from itertools import groupby

a = [{"x":"--New Value","y":20},{"x":"--ANOTHER_VALUE","y":21},{"x":"--New Value","y":27}]

def get_key(d):
    return d['x']

for key, value in groupby(sorted(a, key=get_key), get_key):
    print(key)
    for v in value:
        print(v['y'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this:

```
last = None
for i in a:
    if i["x"] != last:
        print(i["x"])
        last = i["x"]
    print(i["y"])
```

This produces:

```
--New Value
20
21
27
```

It keeps track of the last "x" value, and if the new one differs, it prints it, after which it becomes the new last value of "x".

Note that this preserves the order of the values in the list, so the same "x" value will be repeated if a different one occurs between them.